# datePickerValueChanged Documentation Location?

Tags: uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a code example that uses a - datePickerValueChanged method. Given that I can't find the method in the TableViewController's .h file, I'm assuming that this must be a method in the UIDatePicker class that is being overidden. Would that be correct? If so, where would I find this method documented? I have looked at the iPhone Developer documentation on the developer.apple.com site and a search results in nothing. I can't see it in the UIDatePicker documentation either.

The main reason I ask is that I would like to locate the similar method to override for a UIPickerView object.

I'm not using XIB/Interface Builder for this - the UIDatePicker is created programatically at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a method to the 'valueChanged` event of date picker:

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMyDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

assuming your method is called `changeMyDate:`

Comment: Yeah, silly me. The line you gave me above is what is adding the datePickerValueChanged method - so obviously the method name doesn't matter at all, and its not actually a method that is overriding something from a protocol. Thanks for the nudge - thats helped. On the other hand, I see that for UIPickerView, there is a UIPickerViewDelegate protocol I can implement which gives me pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: to override. Hopefully I understand that the controls, even though they look "the same" are actually quite different to implement.

Comment: the delegate method you mentioned and attached a selector to the 'changed' event are two very different things. If you just want to know that things have changed, use the selector method. You can use the delegate method for more custimization.